# How to pass parameter to Laravel DB::transaction()

Tags: database, transactions, laravel, eloquent

From the laravel documentation: [Database Transaction](http://laravel.com/docs/database#database-transactions).
It says that:

```
DB::transaction(function() {
    DB::table('users')->update(array('votes' => 1));
    DB::table('posts')->delete();
});
```

Here, 1 is explicitly entered to update the users... 
I tried this using a variable,

```
$id = 3;
DB::transaction(function() {
    DB::table('users')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
});
```

It throws an error:

```
Undefined variable: id
```

I also tried to place to $id as a parameter like this:

```
$id = 3;
DB::transaction(function($id) {
    DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
});
```

Still, an error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection could not be converted to string

Have I done anything wrong? Please advise. Thanks...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The `use` keyword is what you need:

```
$id = 3;
DB::transaction(function($id) use ($id) {
    DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
});
```

For PHP 7 (untested, edited as requested by the answer below):

```
$id = 3;
DB::transaction(function() use ($id) {
    DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
});
```

Comment: Recommended lecture: [Anonymous Functions: Closures & Scoping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: If you alter $id inside the closure, will it affect the $id outside?

Comment: @CaptainHypertext Not necessarily, if you want to alter the outside $id, you can just reference it like so: `DB::transaction(function($id) use (&$id) {`

Comment: @Alexandre Danault It would be worth editing this answer reflecting the changes made in PHP 7 (mentioned in the other answer below.)

Comment: In PHP 7 you do not need $id to be placed inside function(). Instead simply pass it inside use() closure. That should be good enough to make the variable available inside the code block.

Answer (score 22):

In PHP 7 the syntax has changed:

```
$id = 3;
DB::transaction(function () use ($id) {
    DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
});
```

Comment: This is clutch.

Comment: This is the new correct answer. 
I had the following error "Cannot use lexical variable $varName as a parameter name" and this answer did the trick. I even updated my composer to update the guzzle to see if it was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To answer @CaptainHypertext question of

> If you alter $id inside the closure, will it affect the $id outside?

This method worked for me:

```
$id = 3;
$transactionResult = DB::transaction(function($id) use ($id) {
 $request_id = DB::table('requests')->insertGetId([
                          'company_id' => $company->$id,
                         ]);
return  $request_id ;
});

echo($transactionResult);
```