# Laravel Transaction Not Reading parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I used Laravel DB transaction to secured my queries but DB:Transaction 

`$request->get('remarks')` or anything from the parameter, Here is my controller: (I already double check my view and may input name is correct).

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
     //dd($request->all());
     //meat Materials

     DB::transaction(function () {
         $formula = new Formula([ 
             'project'      => 'Project',
             'remarks'      => $request->get('remarks'),  
         ]);

         $current = Carbon::now();
         $current = new Carbon();

         //$user=auth()->user();
         $formula->control_number    = '1';
         $formula->prepared_by       = '1';
         $formula->date_prepared     = Carbon::now('Asia/Manila');
         $formula->time_prepared     = Carbon::now('Asia/Manila');
         $formula->status            = 'pending';

         $formula->save();
         $meat = new Meat();
         $meat->control_number    = '1';
         $meat->prepared_by       = '1';
         $meat->save();
    });

    return view('formula.test');
}
```

Comment: [How to pass parameter to Laravel DB::transaction()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17084723/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need pass the variable to the anonymous function:

```
DB::transaction(function ($request) use ($request) {
    $formula = new Formula([ 
        'project'      => 'Project',
        'remarks'      => $request->get('remarks'),  
    ]);
});
```